# Display results from Filter function in a different sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following function which searches data in cells `A7:C14` specifically the middle column (`B7:B14`). As you can see from the picture below, everything is working, I searched for `corola` and I got all of the rows that contain that word.

```
=FILTER(A7:C14,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,B7:B14)))
```

What I would like to be able to do is have the data and the results in different sheets. In other words, ideally I would like to have the `Data` in `Sheet1` and the Searching Results in `Sheet2` but no matter what I do I cannot reference data from `Sheet1`.

I tried...

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A4:C14,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,B4:B14)))
```

But it still references `Sheet2`. Any idea how can I display the search results in a different sheet?

#### This is what currently works, data and results in the same sheet.

[image]

#### This is what I want, data in Sheet1 and the results in Sheet2.

#### Sheet 1

[image]

#### Sheet 2

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `=FILTER(Sheet1!A4:C14,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,Sheet1!B4:B14)))`  You need to put the sheet on the `B4:B14` reference also.

Comment: @ScottCraner - It worked, thanks a lot. One more question, is there a way to widen the search range, instead of searching only the middle column, search all three columns? Also, add your comment as an actual answer to mark it as the right answer.

Comment: You would multiply each boolean expression: `=FILTER(Sheet1!A4:C14,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,Sheet1!B4:B14)))*(boolean2)*(boolean3))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Hmm, adding a second search doesn't give me any errors, I just don't get any results. `=FILTER(Sheet1!A7:C14,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,Sheet1!B7:B14)) * ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F1,Sheet1!A7:A14)))` . Thanks

Comment: That is because you are looking for Corola in the company column. There are none that have corola in both columns.

Comment: I searched for Toyota and I don't get anything, just `#CALC!`.

Comment: IF you are using `F1` in both Searches but searching different columns you will not find any matches.  Because `*` means `AND` if you want to search if a word is in either or then change the `*` to `+` which will then work like `OR`

Comment: Bingo, it worked, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:C9,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,Sheet1!B2:B9)))
```

Add **Sheet1!** for the Range in formula.

[image]